# C++ volatile: guaranteed 32-bit accesses?

Tags: c++, linux, hardware, volatile

In my **Linux C++ project**, I have a **hardware memory region mapped somewhere in the physical address space** which I access using **uint32_t pointers**, after doing a **mmap**.

The **release build** of the application crashes with a **SIGBUS (bus error)**.

**This is happening because the compiler optimizes accesses to the aforementioned hardware memory using 64-bit accesses**, instead of sticking to 32-bit => bus error, **the hardware memory can only be accessed using 32-bit reads/writes**.

I marked the **uint32_t pointer** as **volatile**.

It works. *For this one specific code portion at least*. Because the compiler is told not to do reordering. And most of the time it would have to reorder to optimize.

I know that volatile controls **when** the compiler accesses the memory. The question is: does volatile also tell the compiler **how** to access the memory, i.e. **to access it exactly as the programmer instructs**? **Am I guaranteed that the compiler will always stick to doing 32-bit accesses to volatile uint32_t buffers?**

e.g. Does volatile also guarantee that the compiler will be accessing the **2 consecutive writes to the 2 consecutive 32-bit values** in the following code-snippet using 32-bit reads/writes as well?

```
void aFunction(volatile uint32_t* hwmem_array)
{
    [...]

    // Are we guaranteed by volatile that the following 2 consecutive writes, in consecutive memory regions
    // are not merged into a single 64-bit write by the compiler?
    hwmem_array[0] = 0x11223344u;
    hwmem_array[1] = 0xaabbccddu;

    [...]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I answered my own question, please correct me if I'm wrong.

**C99 standard draft**: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf

Quotes:

“

> 6 An object that has volatile-qualified type **may be modified in ways
>   unknown to the implementation or have other unknown side effects**.
>   Therefore **any expression referring to such an object shall be
>   evaluated** strictly according to the rules of the abstract machine, **as
>   described in 5.1.2.3**. Furthermore, at every sequence point the value
>   last stored in the object shall agree with that prescribed by the
>   abstract machine, except as modified by the unknown factors mentioned
>   previously.

”

Section 5.1.2.3:

“

> 2 **Accessing a volatile object**, modifying an object, modifying a file,
>   or calling a function that does any of those operations are all side
>   effects, which are changes in the state of the execution environment.
>   ***Evaluation of an expression may produce side effects***. At certain
>   specified points in the execution sequence called ***sequence points***, **all
>   side effects of previous evaluations** ***shall be complete and no side
>   effects of subsequent evaluations shall have taken place***. (A summary
>   of the sequence points is given in annex C.)
>
> 5 The least requirements on a conforming implementation are: — At
>   sequence points, **volatile objects are** ***stable*** **in the sense that**
>   ***previous accesses are complete and subsequent accesses have not yet
>   occurred***.

”

Annex C (informative) Sequence points:

“

> 1 The following are the sequence points described in 5.1.2.3:
>
> […]
>
> — The **end of a full expression**: an initializer (6.7.8); the expression
>   in an expression statement (6.8.3); the controlling expression of a
>   selection statement (if or switch) (6.8.4); the controlling expression
>   of a while or do statement (6.8.5); each of the expressions of a for
>   statement (6.8.5.3); the expression in a return statement (6.8.6.4).

”

So theoretically we are guaranteed that **at the end of any expression involving a volatile object, the volatile object is written/read, as the compiler was instructed to do**.

Comment: Agree `hwmem_array[1] = 0xaabbccddu;` happens _after_ `hwmem_array[0] = 0x11223344u;` (not a combined 64-bit write) yet each individual `hwmem_array[x] = ...` is not certain to use a "using 32-bit write" vs say two 16-bit writes.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Hmm, good point. I wonder though if in practice that's true. For example, writing a 32-bit hardware register in 2 shots 16-bit&16-bit, might not be allowed by the hardware. I'm expecting the compiler to also respect the data size, IF possible of course (if it has the possibility to do 32-bit writes at CPU instruction level). But it's a good question whether the standard also guarantees that...

Comment: Corneliu Zuzu Agree about in practice. Yet I am certain the spec does not guarantee single instruction, else same code on a 16-bit machine would necessarily fail to compile.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Yes, that's why I said "IF possible" - meaning, maybe the standard guarantees (maybe in some other paragraph I've missed) that IF the processor can do 32-bit writes, it WILL do them for volatile uint32_t* arrays...it would be good to confirm this.

Comment: I see nothing in the C spec that will provide that comfort.  At the end of the day, either review the emitted code and see it is as needed and trust it will be so in the future (reasonable here) OR write assembly.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Assembly would be the safest option indeed, although much less maintainable than volatile (differences between compilers/architectures). Thank you for your input. In the meantime maybe we'll get lucky and find that second guarantee in the standard